# Is there a way to Insert an extra node whilst copying the links (of various types) to other nodes from an existing node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a challenge I am making no progress with - I can't even list code that isn't working because I can't get near to what I am trying to do!

I start with a node labelled ProductFamily which links to a number of nodes which are derivatives of that base family - label:Derivative. Each Derivative node is then linked to a significant number of other nodes describing various aspects of the derivative and using a range of relationship types: [INTRODUCED_IN], [DISCONTINUED], [HAS_DIMENSION], [USES] and on and on. Because there is never full information on every derivative and every family the number of nodes connected to any given Derivative node and the relationship types will vary wildly. In some cases dozens of nodes downstream from the Derivative node might be present.The diagram  shows a simple example with the node "500" being the target Derivative. I want to introduce a new Derivative -say the "500SS" which shares all the same relationships - because it is then easy to edit the few that change rather than try to make all the duplicates that are required.

I can come up with code that lists all the nodes that the new node would connect to, I can get all the relationship types required but getting both, and getting them associated with each other and merging them with a new node? Not even close! I have found APOC calls that clone paths but that doesn't help because that means duplication the Characteristic nodes which is not wanted (and they are unique anyway).

I have looked at creating most of these relationships from the family node - but that then means you lose consistency from one family to another with respect to which characteristics are Family related and which are Derivative related. So I opted to put ALL characteristic relationships at the Derivative level.

Am i trying to something daft?

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `familyName` is the id of the first node you want to start your query with:

```
MATCH (:ProductFamiliy {name:$familyName})-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(d:Derivative)-[r]->(t)
WITH d, collect(distinct [type(r), t]) AS rels
MERGE (newd:Derivative {name:d.name + "ss"})
WITH newd, rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH newd, rel
CALL apoc.create.relationship(newd, rel[0],{}, rel[1]) yield rel AS rel2
RETURN *
```

Basically we start from the Family node and find all the Derivatives. Then for all derivatives, we keep the connected nodes and their relationship types in `rels`. Then we create all the new Derivatives. Finally we unwind `rels` and then we create all the relationships. We can remove the second line and slightly modify the rest and the query will still work but I did that to avoid running the `MERGE` command multiple times for the same node.

**UPDATE:** 
If you need to connect the new derivative to the Family node, use this:

```
MATCH (f:ProductFamiliy {name:$familyName})-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(d:Derivative)-[r]->(t)
WITH f, d, collect([type(r), t]) AS rels
MERGE (newd:Derivative {name:d.name + "ss"})
MERGE (f)-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(newd)
WITH newd, rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH newd, rel
CALL apoc.create.relationship(newd, rel[0],{}, rel[1]) yield rel AS rel2
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thank you! That moves me a lot further - but not quite all the way there...

Comment: Sorry - posted before I meant to! I had to make some tweaks to allow for constraints that I had not mentioned - so this:

Comment: MATCH (:EngineFamily {name:"Dominator"})-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(d:Derivative {name:"500", family: "Dominator"})-[r]->(t)
WITH d, collect([type(r), t]) AS rels
MERGE (newd:Derivative {name:d.name + "SS", family:d.family})
WITH newd, rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH newd, rel
CALL apoc.create.relationship(newd, rel[0],{}, rel[1]) yield rel AS rel2
RETURN *

got me everything except the link between the original "family"node and the new derivative

Comment: I have tried a few variations on the theme as follows, but they don't work - they tell me the new derivative node has already been created (I have detached and deleted it before running)

MATCH (e:EngineFamily {name:"Dominator"})-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(d:Derivative {name:"500", family: "Dominator"})-[r]->(t)
WITH e, d, collect([type(r), t]) AS rels
MERGE (newd:Derivative {name:d.name + "SS", family:d.family})<-[:HAS_DERIVATIVE]-(e)
WITH newd, rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH newd, rel
CALL apoc.create.relationship(newd, rel[0],{}, rel[1]) yield rel AS rel2
RETURN *

Comment: I am being dim, I need to use the APOC call to create that relationship too - I think

Comment: Sorry, when the "newd" node is properly deleted (without typos!) then the code runs but still does not create the (family)-[HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(newd) relationship

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks, I have run that and it gives exactly the same result as before, it does not create the (f)-[HAS_DERIVATIVE]->(newd) relationship but it does create all the outgoing (newd) relationships

Comment: Sorry when I updated my answer, I changed the first code block by mistake. I fixed it. It should be good now.